# hiding sub menu on left click of mouse button for Mozilla in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

In a web page one "context-menu/subMneu" made up of divs is displayed on hovering over a separate div. This sub-menu is getting closed when user clicked on somewhere else in the document means any mouse click on a document will result in closing of the sub-menu.
In IE8, Chrome12 & Firefox sub-menu is getting closed on left mouse click.

What is happening.In Internet Explorer8 & Chrome12 when we press right mouse button then it is not getting closed. Browser's default menu is getting opened which is a right functionality. But in Mozilla Firefox on clicking right mouse button sub-menu is getting closed.

My problem is why this is happening in Mozilla only and how to resolve it?

Below is the code snippet. I have used detachEvent/deatchEventListener and attachEvent/attachEventListener both because in IE8 does not support deatchEventListener/attachEventListener

Code:

```
function hideSubMenu(){
  doument.getElementById("elem").style.display = none;
  if(document.detachEvent){
     document.detachEvent('onclick',hideSubMenu);
  }
  else(document.detachEventListener){
     document.detachEventListener('click',hideSubMenu,true);
  }
}
#in which Event is attached
function displayMenu(){
   if(document.attachEvent){
      document.attachEvent('onclick',hideSubMenu);
   }
   else(document.attachEventListener){
      document.attachEventListener('click',hideSubMenu,true);
   }
}
```

Note: only javascript I can use.So request you all to keep suggestions keeping this in mind. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems FF triggers `click` with right mouse button too. You can try something like this:

```
function hideSubMenu (e) {
    var menu = document.getElementById('elem');
    if (document.detachEvent) {
        menu.style.display = 'none';
        document.detachEvent('onclick', hideSubMenu);
    } else {
        if (e.which === 1) { // Checks left-click
            document.removeEventListener('click', hideSubMenu);
            menu.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    return;
}

function displayMenu () {
    if (document.attachEvent) {
        document.attachEvent('onclick', hideSubMenu);
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('click', hideSubMenu, false);
    }
    return;
}
```

Working demo in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KeLAw/1/).